# swift write data to plist

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var pliststr:String = "a"
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, World!")
            Text(pliststr)
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.pliststr = self.getPlist(name: "Property List")

            }
        }
    }

    func getPlist(name: String) -> String{
        let unit_path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: name, ofType: "plist")
        let unit_data:NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary.init(contentsOfFile: unit_path!)!
        let unit_String = unit_data["a"]! as! String
        unit_data.setValue("CCC", forKey: "a")
        unit_data.write(toFile: unit_path!, atomically: true)
        print(unit_String)
        return unit_String
    }

}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image]
Here is a demo of r/w plist. Code above can only save "CCC" to ram but the plist file remain unchange.How to save data to the plist file.

Comment: You cannot write into the application bundle, it's read-only (for obvious reasons). And please **never ever** read property lists into `NSMutable...` collection types. There are convenient APIs like `PropertyListSerialization` and `PropertyListEncoder/Decoder`. And this is Swift: *snake_cased* variable names are discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

You can't write to files in your application bundle.  See [Where files reside](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW13) in Apple's File System Programming Guide to see which locations you can write to.  If you want to persist changes to a bundled file, you can save the new version to one of those locations instead.